# Messages are not displayed properly after customizing Alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to add the action "document-edit-properties" in the folder details page. So in share-config-custom.xml I have added the action id in the actionGroup(for id =folder-details) as below. Now the action is visible in the folder details page, but the title and the "All properties" are not displayed properly in the popup.

```
<actionGroup id="folder-details">
            <action index="100" id="folder-download"/>
            <action index="105" id="document-edit-metadata" icon="folder-edit-metadata" label="actions.folder.edit-metadata" />
            <action index="115" id="document-edit-properties" icon="folder-edit-properties" label="actions.folder.edit-metadata" /> 
            <action index="110" id="document-approve" icon="folder-approve" />
            <action index="120" id="document-reject" icon="folder-reject" />
            <action index="130" id="document-copy-to" icon="folder-copy-to" label="actions.folder.copy-to" />
            <action index="140" id="document-move-to" icon="folder-move-to" label="actions.folder.move-to" />
            <action index="150" id="folder-manage-rules" />
            <action index="160" id="document-delete" icon="folder-delete" label="actions.folder.delete" />
            <action index="170" id="document-manage-granular-permissions" icon="folder-manage-permissions" label="actions.folder.manage-permissions" />
            <action index="180" id="document-manage-repo-permissions" icon="folder-manage-permissions" label="actions.folder.manage-permissions" />
            <action index="190" id="document-manage-aspects" label="actions.folder.manage-aspects" />
            <action index="200" id="document-change-type" label="actions.folder.change-type" />
            <action index="210" id="view-in-explorer" />
            <action index="220" id="document-view-in-source-repository" label="actions.folder.view-source-repository" />
            <action index="350" id="document-view-googlemaps" />
            <action index="360" id="document-cloud-sync" />
            <action index="370" id="document-cloud-unsync" />
            <action index="380" id="document-view-in-cloud" />
            <action index="390" id="document-request-sync"/>
         </actionGroup>
```

[image]
Am unable to figure out why message is not proper. In folder browse page the messages are displayed properly.

Alfresco Version : 4.2.6

Can someone please help... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using SDK? what is the location of your .properties file?

Comment: Can you please share your properties file

Comment: @vikas: am reusing the out of box action. So I don't have a separate property file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you add a bean for your message properties and that you specify the properties and labels you need in Share. See http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/kb-preset-internationalization.html for details.

Also, see the answer (at the bottom) of a question about some of this here https://community.alfresco.com/thread/199192-content-model-localization-in-share

So, the fix is what I suggest above. Add a bean to a context file like this

```
   <!-- Add module specific messages and labels -->
   <bean id="org.alfresco.share-amp.resources"
         class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
      <property name="resourceBundles">
         <list>
            <value>alfresco.web-extension.messages.share-amp</value>
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

That bean references a properties file in web-extension/messages named share-amp.properties. It should have the following content.

```
## Edit Details Dialog
edit-details.title=Edit Properties: {0}
edit-details.label.edit-metadata=All Properties...
```

Why do you need to do this? If you look at onActionDetails in actions.js, you'll see that it's trying to resolve those and is not able to. I'm not sure why as I haven't done a lot of YUI/share customization, but what I suggest here will fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its not a custom action. I am reusing the out of box action. So why should I add the bean again?

Comment: Is it means that you are doing changes by modifying the out of the box files.?

Comment: Is this for a custom type on your folder?

Comment: @ vikash and @Jeff R : Thanks for the reply, but am not changing any out of box files. We have an out of box action `document-edit-properties` which is visible only on `folder browse` page. I need it to be visible in folder details page also. So what I did is I have added that action id in `folder-details actionGroup` through 'share-config-custom.xml' file. Now the action is visible in the folder details page and I can edit the properties also, but two of the messages on popup are not being displayed properly.

Comment: I added on to the answer. This should fix it for you. You might also want to update your action label, so they both don't say "Edit Properties".